# matlab help in finding dimensions

Tags: matlab, math, equations

Can anybody help me with this assignment please?
[image]

I am new to matlab, and passing this year depends on this assignment, i don't have much time to explore matlab and i already wasted alot of time trying to do this assignment in my way.
I have already wrote the equations on the paper, but transfering the equations into matlab codes is really hard for me.
All i have for now is:

```
syms h
l = (0.75-h.^2)/(3*sqrt((5*h.^2)/4)); %h is h_max
V_default = (h.^2/2)*l;
dv = diff(V_default); %it's max. when the derivative is max.
h1 = solve( dv ==0);
h_max = (h1>0);
l_max = (0.75-h_max.^2)/(3*sqrt((h_max/2).^2+(h_max.^2)));
V_max = ((h_max.^2)./(2.*l_max));

but it keep give me error "Error using  ./ 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in triangle (line 9)
V_max = ((h_max.^2)./(2.*l_max)); "
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really helping with the assignment here, but with the Matlab syntax. In the following line:

```
l_max = (0.75-h_max.^2)/(3*sqrt((h_max/2).^2+(h_max.^2)));
```

you're using `/` that is a matrix divide. You might want to use `./` which will divide the terms element by element. If I do this

```
l_max = (0.75-h_max.^2) ./ (3*sqrt((h_max/2).^2+(h_max.^2)));
```

then your code doesn't return any error. But I have no idea if it's the correct solution of your assignment, I'll leave that to you!

Answer (score 0):

In line 5, the result `h1` is a vector of two values but the variable itself remains symbolic, from the Symbolic Math Toolbox. MATLAB treats such variables slightly different. For that reason, the line `h_max = (h1>0)` doesn't really do what you expect. As I think from this point, you are interested in one value `h_max`, I would convert `h1` to a regular MATLAB variable and change your code to the following:

```
h1 = double(solve( dv ==0)); % converts symbolic to regular vectors
h_max = h1(h1>0);            % filters out all negative and zero values
l_max = (0.75-h_max.^2)/(3*sqrt((h_max/2).^2+(h_max.^2)));
V_max = ((h_max.^2)./(2.*l_max));
```

EDIT.
If you still have error, it means `solve( ...)` returns more than 1 positive values. In this case, as suggested, use dotted operations, such as `./` but the results in `l_max` and `V_max` will not be a single value but vectors of the same size as `h_max`. Which means you don't have one max Volume.

Comment: Thx Roberto & Celdor :)
Can anybody help with question b ?